# color histogram for images

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

In color histogram, we usually extracts histograms in each color channel, this does not contains the information of how the colors are co-occurred, for example how many pixels have the intensity I(100,200,50)?

Are there any way to build a histogram that represents the co-occurance of colors? (how many pixels contains the intensity value (200,100,50)?)

I am looking for some improved version of this type of histograms for eg. like this [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/68706/cvpr1.pdf)

Comment: It may depend on your purposes. Do you want to visualize it? Or do you want to use it as image-level descriptor?

Comment: I want to use as a descriptor..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to use it as an image-level descriptor for further recognition, simple binning might not be the best option because colours are not distributed uniformly in your sample.

The typical approach is [bag of words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision). You take all the pixel values from your whole set of images (points in 3D space) and quantize them using some clustering algorithm (like [k-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) or [EM algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EM_algorithm)). Suppose you used *K* clusters (may depend on your purposes and sample size, you can start with *K* = 100). To describe an individual image, you find the closest cluster for each pixel (so-called *visual word*), and build the histogram with *K* bins, so that each bin value is the number of pixels corresponding to the visual word. This is your descriptor, and you can compare images using Euclidean distance or χ² distance over descriptors.

Note that there are a lot of implementations of clustering algorithms (and even bag-of-words frameworks) available, depending on your platform. [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) is among the most popular ones. Note that you can also use gradient-based descriptors like [HOG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients), depending on your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I found the following interesting 'Object Recognition with Color Cooccurrence Histograms' at http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/68706/cvpr1.pdf

Comment: Computer vision made a big progress over the last decade, so the paper may be far from state-of-the-art.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I think it s not far from state of the art. It is like a new kind of descriptor. I went through several papers and found this is useful and cited by many other papers. But still unable to figure out how to effeciently implement that paper. It would be useful if anyone could help me to give me some hints to effeciently implement it.

Answer (score 6):

You can either build a really big histogram with 256^3 values, or you can quantize the values in each channel (e.g. 10 values per channel) which would lead to a histogram with 1000 entries.

Comment: This is an appropriate approach, but the used bins will probably be quite sparse. One can instead hash all three values together to get a long and then use that as a key into a hash table.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you just answered your own question.

Yes, it is possible to build such a histogram. It should be fairly simple in terms of implementation, since usually `(r,g,b)` is represented by 32 bits where the first three are `r`,`g` and `b`